# A simpler solution for a geometric problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider the parallelogram in figure, where $d=\overline{DB}=15$ and $a=\overline{AH}=6$. Furthermore, assume that $\widehat{ADB}$ is a right angle. Find the perimeter.

[image]

My solution:
let's call $h=\overline{DH}$ and $b=\overline{HB}$, then
$$
a:h=h:b\implies h^2=ab\\
h^2+b^2=d^2 \implies b^2+ab-d^2=0
$$
the last one is a quadratic equation in the unknown $b$. From now on it is easy to procede.

Now, my question: there is a simpler solution, for a 12 year old student that still don't know quadratic equations?

Comment: I don't think so. The known lengths and angles are delicately poised to give a unique solution, where getting to that solution requires quadratics.

Comment: The quadratic is $b(6 + b) = 15^2$. It is easy to write down all pairs of integers whose product equals $15^2$ and see if any differ by 6. Now here the problem is that none of them do. But if you change either the 6 or the 15 or both of them so that there will be an integer solution the problem might be doable without knowing the general theory of quadratic equations.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. This is not a problem I am preparing, but a problem that someone else assigned to a student, and I thought I was me to be unable to find a simple solution.

Comment: is $DH$ perpendicular to $AB$?

Comment: @JohnGlennLambayon: yes, of course, sorry to not being clear about that